# $L=\{<M>|M~is~a~TM~and~L(M)=\{0^n1^n|n\ge0\}\}$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, automata, reductions

About the language $L=\{<M>|M~is~a~TM~and~L(M)=\{0^n1^n|n\ge0\}\}$

I want to determine if it is in RE / coRE or neither.

I think that I found a mapping reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ to $L$, where
$\overline{A_{TM}}=\{<M,w>|M~is~a~TM~and~M~does~not~accept~w\}$:

Define $f(<M>)=<N_{M,w}>$ as follows:

$N_{M,w}=$ "On input $x$:

1. If $x='01'$, accept
2. Run $M$ on $w$ and do as $M$ does."

So if $<M,w>\in\overline{A_{TM}}$ we have $L(N_{M,w})=\{01\} \in L$.

If $<M,w>\notin\overline{A_{TM}}$ we have $L(N_{M,w})=\Sigma^* \notin L$

But I don't know if I am able to construct a TM for $\overline{L}$ or find another reduction from a RE language to $L$.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can your Rice theorem for the other direction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want ro prove that L-complement is RE, you can construct a TM which enumerates L-complement. L-complement contains the M's which are not some Turing machine's code or they are code of Turing machines that accept some input which is not in the form of 0'1' . If such an input exists, It can be computably found. So L-complement is re because both following sets are re:

A = { < M > | M is not a Turing machine code.}

B = {< M > | M is a Turing machine which accepts some input which is not in the form of 0'1'}

And

L-complement = A U B

It is a theorem that if A and B are r.e sets, then so is A U B